# What are these red dots on my Google Cluster Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image: Google Cluster Map]

I am using a Google Cluster map to generate the markers seen in this map.  However, I cannot find any documentation regarding these red dots.

When I zoom in, the dots are anchored to the bottom of the individual markers.

[image: Zoomed In]

Has anyone seen this before?  Did Google update their API?  Does anyone have any additional information?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly traffic?

Comment: When I zoom in, the red dots turn into the individual locations.  It's as if they are the locations that don't fall within the cluster.  Updated question with screenshot.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example?

Comment: You can see it happening here if you zoom into Hawaii:  https://demo.geomywp.com/posts-locator-global-map/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, not (just) a link to an external site.